# EDO without solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

There no answer to the following EDO:
$xy'-y=x^2;y(0)=-2$, because on $0$ the first equation is $y(0)=0$.
Am I correct?
This does not match with existence's theorem because $a(x)=x$ is null at $0$?

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, as you will notice when solving the ODE, no solution can contain the point $x=0$

Comment: $1/x$ is not continuous on any interval that contains $0$... So there isn't a solution to the IVP

Comment: Thank you so much.